# Custom Serialization finds incorrect "response" in Alamofire 4.0

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift3

I'm attempting to define a custom model serialization for Alamofire 4.0.  So far I'm following the model presented used by `responseJson` and friends.  Specifically, what I have so far is:

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    public static func serializeResponseModel<T:ModelObject>(response:HTTPURLResponse?, data:Data?, error:Error?) -> Alamofire.Result<T> {
        switch serializeResponseJSON(options: [], response: response, data: data, error: error) {
        case .success(let jsonObject):
            do {
                return .success(try T(json:jsonObject as! JSONObject))
            }
            catch {
                return .failure(error)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}

extension Alamofire.DataRequest {
    public static func serializeResponseModel<T:ModelObject>() -> DataResponseSerializer<T> {
        return DataResponseSerializer { _, response, data, error in
            return Request.serializeResponseConcierge(response: response, data: data, error: error)
        }
    }

    @discardableResult
    public func responseModel<T:ModelObject>(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void) -> Self
    {
        return response(
            queue: queue,
            responseSerializer: DataRequest.serializeResponseModel(),
            completionHandler: completionHandler
        )
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the framework is somewhat poorly implemented and the line `return response(` is finding the `response` property (defined in `Request`) and not the appropriate `response` method (defined in `DataRequest`), which leads to the compile error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'
```

What am I missing here that allows this to work in the `responseJson` case, but not in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem arose from over-generalization, and the compiler not being able to generate an appropriate type for `DataRequest.serializeResponseModel()`  When I changed `responseModel` to the following and specified the appropriate type, things work as expected:

```
@discardableResult
public func responseModel<T:ModelObject>(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void) -> Self
{
    return response(
        queue: queue,
        responseSerializer: DataRequest.modelResponseSerializer() as DataResponseSerializer<T>,
        completionHandler: completionHandler
    )
}
```